# How can keyframes of properties be added to an action?

Tags: animation, game-engine

I tried to add keyframes for the emission value of a material to an action, but couldn't find out how.

Adding keyframes for a object's location works as expected but properties like emission only show up in the *Timeline* and *Curve Editor*.

A MaterialAction is created (only visible in the *NLA Editor*) toggling to edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> the keyframes are displayed in the time line. This MaterialAction is not accesible from the *Action Editor*.

[image]

EDIT:

Fweebs suggestion to use a driver works unfortunatly only in the *3D-Viewport* but not in the BGE. I didn't ask specifically for the BGE because I was hoping for a common solution that works everywhere.

[image]

[image]

.blendfile [here](http://www.filedropper.com/propertyanim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly, but you can use a driver that ties the property value to the location of an object (typically an Empty or a bone in an armature) in your scene. That animation can be included in an action.

Comment: Without details of how to do this, this answer is largely useless.

Comment: Setting up drivers is a somewhat involved process and it's important to know what the ultimate goal is. Based on the question, this *appears* to be a rigging situation (which would be best suited using a bone in an armature), but we don't know for certain, so it was best to answer generally. In any case, more detail on drivers is available on the wiki (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers)

Comment: You should include the link in your answer. It is more useful to other users that way. (And btw, forgive my "tone" I'm just trying to help :D)

Answer (score 3):

As the tooltip mentioned:

> Edit keyframes in active object's Object-level action.

So I bet that is why it is not currently supported yet?

[image]

However, you can still tweak it in the Dope Sheet mode, and use the Filter button to block other action types, if helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a way to invoke the action in the BGE I'm currently experimenting with drivers but this makes things more complicated, once I saw a color changing action in the Action Editor it should be possible (perhaps the file was created with an older version).